# How do I block certain URLs using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Currently everything is working golden except for the fact that a user could manually put in a URL, which messes up how CI is setup for my site. For instance:

`www.somesite.com/folder/`

this folder in the controller should not be accessible... and needs to redirected to that folders index page, which will give them a 404 error. I've tried adding deny to all in the htaccess file, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

`www.somesite.com/folder/index.html`

I actually want all folders to function likes this. I do have an index.html file in the folder, but it doesn't get read. Is there a way to fix this in CI? I'm also having an issue with users being able to manually access the controller functions. I've tried to change them to private as people have suggested, but then my scripts can't access them. For instance:

`www.somesite.com/controller_file/some_function`

How do I block them from accessing this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a whitelist sollution:

1. Open your  application/config/routes.php
2. add the routes you want to allow.
3. add a catchall route `.*` And redirect it to a errot handler

Codeigniters trys to matches the route patterns in the order they are listed in the array so
whenever a user enters a route you did not explicitly allow it will allqays redirect him to the catchall route

[user-guide on routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

EDIT:
You can create a blacklist logic by redirecting only requests matching a specific pattern, and keep the default behaviour for all others.

Comment: Ok, so how would I set a route for www.somesite.com/folder/ ? I have tried $route['folder/'] = 'error_mess';

Comment: I got it!!! So if I wanted to try and block the user from accessing the controller functions I could simply do this: $route['account/account/(:any)'] = 'error_mess';

Comment: Would doing this to every controller than has a function in it be a bad thing?

Comment: If you want to blockk a lot of functions you are better of setting only explicitly allowed routes and catch the rest with a catchall route. This does add some overhead when adding new controllers but imho using a whitelist for allowed routes is the best way to prevent users from calling functions.

Comment: You should not have to worry about specific functions because if you do not want them to be used by users you should stick ith the underscore naming onvention (see Jeemusu´s answers)

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the answer either...if you restrict access with routes.php, even AJAX requests won’t be able to access it since it’s prohibited.

Comment: @KraigBalla Sorry seems I did not understand you. You can not blcok functions to users and still use them for ajax calls, becuase both are http requests. There are some ways to make calling functions harder but since the call is done via a client side script a user can always figure out how to fake a ajax request. The only safe and proper way is to check if the call is valid on the server side. If your controller function may only be called by a admin your controller must check if the user is logged in as admin. Your controller should NEVER assume that only valid requests are made!

Answer (score 1):

As far as denying access to the filesystem goes, your best bet would be to to place your `Application` and `System` folders outside of the webroot. Then edit your index.php to set the new path to each folder. My general set up looks like this:

```
+ Root
| - Application
| - System
| + Webroot
| | - js
| | - css
| | - index.php
| | - ...
+ - ...
```

As for your second question, to prevent certain functions from being accessed directly from the url you need to prepend them with an underbar.

So instead of

`public function some_function() {...}`

Use 
`public function _some_function() {...}`

It can then be called in your controller with `$this->_some_function();`

If you have any AJAX functions, you'll need to drop the underbar from their name to make them accessible. You can stop users accessing them directly from the URL by wrapping your functions with the following conditional.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')) {}
```

The above checks if the request is via AJAX.

Comment: I thought it worked but it doesn't...I have an ajax call that calls a certain function and when I add the underbar, yes it does prevent me from accessing it directly, but it also prevents that ajax request or any form action for that matter.

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer? Anyway, for AJAX requests you'll need to drop the underbar from your functons, but add a condition that checks to see if data has been posted by ajax, thus stopping users from accessing it directly from the URL. See my updated answer.

Comment: Because I thought it worked but when I use the underscore you cannot access the function on form submit or ajax requests. I saw your edit about the AJAX and that would work...but what about if it's a form submission?

Comment: If it's a form submission, you just check if it's been posted, or has post data.